# Unable to return an error from my remote event receiver to our power-app edit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, remote-event-receiver, powerapps-forms

I am developing a remote event receiver and inside the ItemUpdating event , i am returning an error as follow:-

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {   //code goes here...
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
            result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelWithError;
            result.ErrorMessage = "Error while processing your request";
            return result;
        }
```

If i use the SharePoint built-in forms, the error message will be shown inside the edit form, but when using an edit form which has been customized using PowerApp the error message will not be shown inside the powerapp form, and the powerapp form will not get submitted (which is good). so can anyone advice how we can return an error from our RER and show it inside our powerapp form?
Thanks